# How to show Call Stack windows in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I expected to find them under the Debug menu, then Windows but the call stack isn't there in visual studio 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's under Debug > Windows, but you only see it *when your application is running*:

**[image: strong text]**

When your application isn't running, the menu is quite short:

[image]

Comment: Oh sorry i don't know how to accep it but  i will search it and sure i will accept your answer